# KDB+/Q: How to get all rows within a given time or within a given number of rows?

Tags: kdb

How does one create a selection with a lookback window in either time or in row count using KDB+/Q?

i.e. Given the following table:

```
time (seconds) | val
---------------------
1              | 5
2              | 6
3              | 7
4              | 8
6              | 9
```

how does one most efficiently:

- a) select the get the last row and previous 2 rows given the last row i.e. `([]time:3,4,6; val:7,8,9)`
- b) select the events greater than or equal to 2 seconds old i.e. `([]time:4,6; val:8,9)`

**I have tried wj and xbar**, which both work well on an entire table however, I am looking for the 2 functions in this instance that can be applied to a single row (and its respective lookback window) efficiently.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a sort of general approach which solves both of your problems:

```
q)t:([]time:1 2 3 4 6;val:5 6 7 8 9)

/get last row and previous 2
q)select from t where {x|next x}/[2;time=6]
time val
--------
3    7
4    8
6    9

/or alternatively (depending on exactly how you define "last row")
select from t where {x|next x}/[2;time=max time]
select from t where {x|next x}/[2;i=4]

/events >=2 seconds old (and the previous 1)
q)select from t where {x|next x}/[1;2<=deltas time]
time val
--------
4    8
6    9
```